# Is it possible to create an iframe with Javascript that takes over the entire page almost like a URL masking?

Tags: javascript

So I want an iframe to take over the entirety of the page, with the ability to scroll up and down.

```
<iframe src="http://IFRAMEURL.COM"></iframe>
```

Let's say it will get embedded on another website called http://www.ANOTHERSITEURL.com/page1.php

How do I use Javascript to make my iframe containing http://IFRAMEURL.COM take up the entire page of http://www.ANOTHERSITEURL.com/page1.php

So basically it would almost look like domain masking, where you see the page for http://IFRAMEURL but the URL bar shows http://www.ANOTHERSITEURL.com/page1.php

How would I do this with a pure Javascript solution? Also consider that IFRAMEURL.COM will be different than ANOTHERSITEURL.COM

NOTE: So I need a pure javascript solution. A 3rd party user will be using this code on their site to embed my URL. I DON'T have control of anothersiteurl.com/page1.php

Comment: Just using this: `html,body,iframe{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%}` **[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/eeyta6xj/)**.

Comment: "it will get embedded" do you mean someone else framing your page, or do you have control of anothersiteurl.com/page1.php ?

Comment: So I need a pure javascript solution. A 3rd party user will be using this code on their site. I DON'T have control of anothersiteurl.com/page1.php